# permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, openssh

2 days ago I was able to connect to my EC2 instance using the private_key.pem with ssh protocol but today when I tried to do the connection the terminal gives me:

permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

I removed the user called jhon and all the home of that user, then I created again and do the same steps for create the public and private key:

0. adduser jhon2 | su jhon2
1. cd /home/jhon2/
2. ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM (all the questions ENTER by default)
3. cd .ssh/ | cat id_rsa.pub > authorized_keys
4. chmod 600 authorized_keys

-- I create a newest .pem file called jhon2.pem which contains the id_rsa content (private_key)

And from my laptop I tried again the ssh -i /home/macos/pems/jhon2.pem jhon2@instance-id, but nothing again...

- The SELINUX was disabled
- The sshd service status was OK
- I can connect to root and ec2-user
- command: telnet {instance-id} 22 : OK

I don´t know what is going on :s

Comment: Did the public key pem file come from step #2? How did you move it from the EC2 instance to your own computer?

Comment: I copied the content of the id_rsa, cause I used the SSM connection and I´m able to copy and paste to my host clipboard (this method always worked for me)

Answer (score 6):

To reproduce your situation, I launched a new Amazon Linux 2 instance and did the following:

On the EC2 instance:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-96 ~]$ sudo adduser jhon4
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-0-96 ~]$ sudo su jhon4
[jhon4@ip-172-31-0-96 ec2-user]$ cd /home/jhon4
[jhon4@ip-172-31-0-96 ~]$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/jhon4/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/home/jhon4/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/jhon4/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/jhon4/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
[jhon4@ip-172-31-0-96 ~]$ cd .ssh
[jhon4@ip-172-31-0-96 .ssh]$ cat id_rsa.pub >authorized_keys
[jhon4@ip-172-31-0-96 .ssh]$ chmod 600 authorized_keys 
[jhon4@ip-172-31-0-96 .ssh]$ cat id_rsa
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I then copied the private key to my local computer and used:

```
$ ssh -i jhon.pem jhon4@13.211.211.54
Last login: Tue Dec  1 09:57:15 2020

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
[jhon4@ip-172-31-0-96 ~]$
```

So, it worked fine for me. (I had to use `sudo` for some of the commands.)